# Check if word is in a series, then delete it from a string

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-munging, data-wrangling

I'm a beginner in Pandas, I'd like to know how it is possible to write code for the following logical operation that I'd like to perform.

Can someone let me know how they would do this?

If word is in a pandas Series, then delete the word from the string in a DataFrame.

Let Series "A" be a panda Series as follows:

```
index             word
0                 foo
1                 bar
2                 baz
```

---

Let DataFrame "B" be the DataFrame we would like to modify.

```
index    string
0        foo bar hello there
1        foo Lax
2        bar Kay
3        John Smith
```

---

Desired Output:

```
0 hello there
1 Lax
2 Kay
3 John Smith
```

Comment: any of the word from series A or word corresponding to the same index of series B?

Answer (score 4):

Let's try this using `.str.replace` with a regex expression created by using `join`:

```
s = pd.Series(['foo','bar','baz'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'string':['foo bar hello there', 'foo Lax', 'bar Kay', 'John Smith']})

df['string'].str.replace('|'.join(s), '')
```

Output:

```
0      hello there
1              Lax
2              Kay
3       John Smith
Name: string, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting, could you explain what the '|' and the join(s) do here?

Comment: @jerof `'|'.join(s)` creates this string from s, "foo|bar|baz", this is a regular expression where | means OR.

Comment: Thanks! Very clear, would your approach change if one of the strings was "foob barb"? What I'm trying to get at is what happens when the words in the series "s" are part of a coherent phrase/word in the df['string']. The output would then be "b b" as foo and bar would be replaced by ' '. Do you think there is a way to prevent this?

Comment: You can add that to your string or find a regex replacement.  I think "foo[b]?" is the correct regex, but I would need to test.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the leftover leading white space:

```
df['string'].str.replace('|'.join(s), '').str.lstrip()
```